# Text editor having a search box without max length

Tags: php, dreamweaver, text-editor, search-box

I'm working with Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 and the search box has a max length for the query. I'm looking for a text editor having a search box without max length. Any idea?

The thing is that I have created a page from another page a few months ago. I changed a lot of lines and now, I'm trying to check if some parts are still exactly the same to simplify my code and include external php files instead.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "diff" it compares text line by line

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

If you are using windows there is WinMerge

Mac has Xcode

Linux has Meld, Kdiff3, diff

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! I also found this for short queries: http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/